# Tidally locked planet with day & night cycle

Tags: science-based, planets, astronomy

I'm wondering if it is possible for a planet to have one pole always facing its star, the other always facing away (by rotating as if a tidal-locked planet), but style have a day and night cycle on some part of it (by having another axis of rotation ?).

In case I'm not clear enough, I drew this wonderful paint schema to illustrate :
[image: Illustration]

Is it possible for a planet to rotate in a way that would allow this ?

Would there be another natural way to achieve the same result outside of the rotation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did say "on some part of it", so both of these possibilities are pretty restricted.

### Eclipses

The planet has a large, low moon that regularly eclipses part of the surface.

### Wobble

Although the planet is tidally locked, it only got there in the (geologically) recent past, and it still has some wobble, aka [nutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutation).  This will provide a day-night cycle near the twilight area.

Comment: I have been reflecting on your answer and the one below yours, and it made me realize I asked the wrong question. I was too narrow-minded when visualizing my problem, as the tidal-locking is not mandatory for my need. I will ask another question, the right one this time, without merging my hypotheses with my real need. Sorry for the inconvience.
On a side note, I liked your moon idea, I didn't think of using a moon this way and it opens some nice possibilities. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

No.

What you describe is actually a planet with two axes of rotation, which is unstable short-term and would violate the [conservation of angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) long-term, as momentum is additive.

The closest natural phenomenon to what you've described is called  [precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession), but it occurs on a time scale measured in tens of thousands years and not, too my knowledge, at orthogonal angles.

See also [essentially a duplicate question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21580/what-is-the-viability-of-a-planet-rotating-on-two-axes).